# Strange behavior on my netlify subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, netlify

I am using nextjs, aws services (S3, cognito) and mysql and I have my site on netlify, where the production branch is main and the test branch is develop, the situation is the following from one day to the next without making changes to main the production domain mixed data from different users, however both local and the test domain worked perfectly.

After investigating, it was decided to change the production domain and that fixed it. then the previous production domain was used to test and find the problem but now I mix data from different databases (the production db and the test db). Have you had similar experiences, how did you solve it?